# How do I deploy my WPF app to my client's computer?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, deployment, publish

I've spent so much time on the internet to find a way to deploy my WPF application on my client's computer using versioning, remote update etc.. but I wasn't able to find something clear to understand for me.
This is my first app deployment. I've tried to use ClickOnce but can't find the Publish Wizard for a WPF project in VS 2019.
Does anybody have a useful link, tuto or anything to understand from scratch how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: [MSIX: The Modern Way to Deploy Desktop Apps on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/june/devops-msix-the-modern-way-to-deploy-desktop-apps-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to have to install the Click-Once publishing tools using the Visual Studio installer. In the installer components tab search for *Click Once*. Then, you should be able to access the publishing option by selecting your project, right-click and choose *Publish* or using the Menu *Build > Publish* .

There are lots of in-detail explantions about Click Once by Microsoft [in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2019). You should find everything you need there, including steps to publish an application.